# Генерация методов для codeception functional тестов

Tags: yii2, testng, codeception

Хочу потестировать приложение с помощью:

```
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see('Something');
```

и тд.

Но вот проблема:

```
Call to undefined method site\tests\FunctionalSiteTester::amOnPage
```

Дергал команду

```
codecept build
```

Генерил cest файлики, но без толку - в сгенереном классе нет нужных методов.

Вопрос - что надо сделать, чтобы они там появились?

functional.suite.yml:

```
actor: FunctionalSiteTester
bootstrap: false
modules:
enabled:
    - \site\tests\Helper\Functional
    - Yii2:
        part: fixtures
        transaction: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большое спасибо за оперативный ответ официальной страничке на facebook https://www.facebook.com/codeception/

Чтобы появились нужные методы надо убрать из suite конфига строку с part.
Строка говорит, что будут использоваться только то, что в ней перечислено и другие хелпер-методы генериться не будут.